# F# Avoid using mutable varible while submitting result of previos function call

Tags: .net, f#, immutability

I need to use each element of List as an argument when calling the function with 2 arguments. Each function call must submit result of the previous one as second argument!

Is it possible without using mutable variable(to do it in clean functional way:) ? The closest thing I found is List.fold but it makes calculation between list members and accumulates result which is not what I need.

```
let numbersList = [1..5]

let addStringToNumber (x:int) (letter:string) = 
    // Some stub logic here
    if x <> 3 then x.ToString() + letter
    else x.ToString() + "Hello"


let addStringToAllNumbers (numberslist:list<int>) (letter:string) =
    let mutable tempString = letter 
    for i in numberslist do       
        tempString <- addStringToNumber i tempString
    tempString
```

Comment: Why isn't `List.fold (fun tempString i -> addStringToNumber i tempString) letter numberslist)` what you want?

Comment: @Lee Could you post an answer with a full code?

Comment: Opinion: there's nothing particularly "not clean" about using mutable variables in this way. Your function is still pure, i.e. it doesn't cause side-effects. If that's the most obvious/fast way of implementing it, by all means, use a mutable variable. Mutable state that gets passed around multiple functions and side-effects can make code difficult to understand and maintain; this does not.

Comment: The second sentence in your question, "Each function call must submit result of the previous one as second argument", is precisely the situation in which `fold` is what you want. That's a pattern you'll want to notice and learn: if you have a group of items (whether it's a list, a sequence, an array, or some other data type) and you want to take them one at a time and do some operation to them, *and each time the operation needs to be based on the result of the previous operation*... that's the pattern that should make you say "Ah-ha! I need the `fold` function."

Comment: For the fun of it, [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L218) is the F# `List.fold` implementation... which uses a mutable accumulator ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example returns `543Hello` when I run it interactively.  As Lee mentions in a comment, this is the same result that would be returned by `numbersList |> List.fold (fun acc cur -> addStringToNumber cur acc) letter`, which would be the idiomatic way of performing such an operation in F#.  Don't let the name "accumulator" throw you off, a `fold` can be used to do lots of different things.  The "accumulator" is just the value returned by the `fold` of the previous element in the list, which in your case is discarded when the element is 3.

```
let numbersList = [1..5]

let addStringToNumber (x:int) (letter:string) = 
    // Some stub logic here
    if x <> 3 then x.ToString() + letter
    else x.ToString() + "Hello"


let addStringToAllNumbers (numberslist:list<int>) (letter:string) =
    numbersList |> List.fold (fun acc cur -> addStringToNumber cur acc) letter

addStringToAllNumbers numbersList "A"
```

Returns:

```
val it : string = "543Hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Lee in a comment and clarified by @Aaron, `fold` is the best way to do this.

If you wanted another alternative that also avoids mutation, then you could implement a recursive function. This is a low-level functional solution (and I'd pretty much always prefer `fold`), but just for the record, here is an example of doing the same thing using recursion:

```
let addStringToAllNumbers (numberslist:list<int>) (letter:string) =
    let rec loop tempString numberslist =
      match numberslist with 
      | [] -> tempString
      | i::rest -> loop (addStringToNumber i tempString) rest
    loop letter numberslist
```

Comment: And of course, this is pretty much exactly [how fold is often implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Implementation).